# Changing data in table according to date

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a table Program with 3 columns prog_status, opening_date and closing_date. The opening date and closing date values I am retrieving from the user. Now I want the program status to change with respect to the date. So if my current systems date doesn't fall in the opening and closing date the status should show a string value 'Inactive' and if it does fall within the opening and closing date range, the status should be shown as 'Active'. This data needs to be shown in a gridview(code below):-

```
<asp:GridView class="table table-bordered table-hover text-nowrap" Border="0" ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                                                <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">  
                <ItemTemplate>  
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#  Bind("prog_status") %>'></asp:Label>  
                </ItemTemplate>  
            </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Opening Date">  
                <ItemTemplate>  
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#  Bind("prog_open_date") %>'></asp:Label>  
                </ItemTemplate>  
            </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Closing Date">  
                <ItemTemplate>  
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%#  Bind("prog_close_date") %>'></asp:Label>  
                </ItemTemplate>  
            </asp:TemplateField>
                        
                         
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Edit:-
I added the following code in my aspx.cs file but the value for status column is still showing null value.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(//My data source);        

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd2 = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd2.CommandText = SELECT prog_open_date, prog_close_date, prog_status = CASE WHEN GETDATE() >= prog_open_date and GETDATE() <= prog_close_date THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Inactive' END FROM Programs ;
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that prog_status should be a derived column in your database if it's value is always dependant on the system date and the value of prog_open_date and prog_close_date

> A derived column is also known as a computed column, or a calculated field. This column is not physically stored in the database, and is only calculated when the query is run. Derived columns use the value of other column(s) to generate a new field.

If you are using a SQL database you could use the below SQL statement

```
SELECT prog_open_date, prog_close_date, prog_status =   
      CASE          
         WHEN GETDATE() >= prog_open_date and GETDATE() <= prog_close_date THEN 'Active'
         ELSE 'Inactive'  
      END  
FROM Program
```